# How do I import a mixin from an embeded folder in components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is probably really easy, but i dont know what it's called so i dont know what to google for.

My filestructure is like this:

```
 src
   ├──components
   |         └──SomeComponentGroup
   |                       └──Button1.vue
   |
   |
   ├──mixins
   |     └──MyMixin.js
```

How do i import MyMixin from Button1? `import MyMixin from '../mixins/MyMixins.js'` doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something? You just need to go one more up like `import MyMixin from '../../mixins/MyMixins.js'`

Comment: Ah sorry i didnt knew that you could do it like that. But just tried `@/mixins/MyMixins.js;` and that seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it was really easy. `@/mixins/MyMixins.js;` was the solution